# Export multiple files at once to dropbox using filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

I want to use [filepicker.io javascript API](https://www.filepicker.io/) to export multiple image files to dropbox, but I find out it could only export one file at a time.

Is there a way to export multiple files to a folder in dropbox using `filepicker.io`?

Answer (score 1):

The current API does not support multiple file export, but it is on the roadmap.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way to export multiple files using filepicker api?